# How can I decrease the value of a variable by 0.2 every 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I decrease the value of a  variable by 0.2 every 5 minutes?

I have a variable `var = 7.2`. Now I added a button so when I <kbd>click</kbd> on it the variable will increment by 1.

Now I want to add an option where the variable decrement by 0.2 every 5 minutes and stop at the original number 7.2.

I have already tried `window.setInterval()` without successs.

Comment: can you post the code ?

Comment: What code did you use with `setInterval`? How did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
function myFunction(){
    if (counter === 0){
         document.getElementById("dicht").src = "images/open.jpg";
         degree = degree + 0.9;
         temp.innerHTML = degree; //+ " " + "graden celsius in de wijnkoeler";
         counter = 1;
     } else if (counter === 1){
         document.getElementById("dicht").src = "images/dicht.jpg";
         var id = window.setInterval(function(){
             degree = parseFloat(Math.max(7.2, (degree - 0.2)).toPrecision(2));
             if(degree == 7.2){
                 window.clearInterval(id);
                 counter = 0;
             }
             temp.innerHTML = degree;
         }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
     }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty solid.

Comment: thanks  man it worked!!! but now i when i press on the button it wont add 0.9 again. you know how i can fix that

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use [setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/pG29A/)

```
var number;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (number < 7.2 ) clearInterval(interval);
    number = number - 0.2;
}, 300000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's done by using `setInterval`

```
var time = 7.2;
var fivemin = 300000;
$('someid').text(time);
setInterval(function(){
    time = time - 0.2;
    $('someid').text(time);    
}, fivemin);
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/XZdZv/)

Comment: Why do you have `parseFloat`?

Comment: Because it is an Floating value so if we add then result is also in float.@Juan Mendes

Comment: It's not needed, `parseFloat` takes a `String`, and you're passing it a `Number`

Comment: @ Juan Mendes ,Thanks for clearing my confusion..   :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setInterval, use setTimeout instead:

```
window.myVar = 7.2;

var incrementVar = function() {
  window.myVar += 1;
}

var decrementVar = function() {
  window.myVar -= 0.2;
  setTimeout(decrementVar, (5 * 60 * 1000));
}
setTimeout(decrementVar, (5 * 60 * 1000));
```

And for the button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="incrementVar();">My Button</a>
```

Comment: Why not? `setInterval` would work fine. There's a reason to use `setTimeout` (if your function could take a long time) but it's not the case here. If you're going to say don't use something, please add an explanation. Also, if you want it done every 5 seconds, you have to keep track of how long since the last function finished and adjust how long to wait...

Comment: setInterval is more confusing and unnecessary, tho OP wanted 5 minutes not 5 seconds and the time it takes to decrement one variable is negligible.

Comment: @user3058036 You should be able to apply it to your code. Asking others to write your code for you is frowned upon. You should try it and if you can't get it working, post a separate question (linked to this). That keeps this answer useful to other people too without adding noise.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
// global variable
var myGlobal = 8.2;

window.onload = function countback() {
    window.setInterval(function cb() {
        if (myGlobal >= 7.4) {
            myGlobal = parseFloat(myGlobal - .2).toFixed(1);
        }
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
};
```

NOTE: If you are using a JS library like jQuery some of this can be done much more easily.